# Could someone elaborate what it means for there to be an inverse relation between transformations on function space and transformation on coordinates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

In page 67 of Ballentine's Quantum mechanics, he is talking about Galilean Transformations. He has

$\Psi'(x)=U(\tau)\Psi(x)$
Where the original funciton is defined around $x_0$ and the transformed function is defined around $x_0'=\tau x_0$
He states that the precise relationship between the two functions is $\Psi'(\tau x)=\Psi(x)$ and I dont understand where this relationship comes from.

Answer (score 2):

The motivation behind writting down the expression $\Psi'(\tau x)=\Psi(x)$ has to do with the fact that under a transformation that transforms spacetime points, i.e. $x\rightarrow x'=\tau x$, various functions are also transformed into $\Psi\rightarrow\Psi'$. The new transformed functions describe some physical quantity such as some sort of field, and hence they take as arguments the transformed spacetime points $x'$. Hence, under the $x\rightarrow x'=\tau x$ transformation, the function $\Psi(x)$ transforms as $\Psi(x)\rightarrow\Psi'(x')=\Psi'(\tau x)$

The statement that $\Psi'(\tau x)=\Psi(x)$ means that the value of the function $\Psi$ (which might represent some physical field) is left unchanged under those transformations... In those cases, we say that $\Psi$ transforms as a scalar under the transformations $x\rightarrow x'$, because scalars tend to remain the same under an arbitrary transformation.

An equivalent way you might see the statement above in the literature is
$$\Psi'(x)=\Psi(\tau^{-1}x)$$

I hope this helps

Comment: Could you by any chance give an example of  a function and a transformation that explains this?

Comment: A periodic wave function is a nice example I think. The wave function $\Psi(t,x)$ is the solution to the Schroedinger equation. If we require the wave function to be periodic, this means that there exists some $L$ such that $\Psi(t,x+L)=\Psi(t,x)$ (the same goes for $\Psi(t,x+2L)=\Psi(t,x)$, $\Psi(t,x+3L)=\Psi(t,x)$ etc, but this is not the point). You can think of the transformation above as a translation transformation, i.e. $x\rightarrow x'=x+L$. An observer living in a universe that is transformed solves the Schroedinger equation and obtains a wave function $\Psi'(t,x')$.

Comment: The only difference is that the he/she solves the same Schroedinger equation as with one that lives in the non-trasformed universe and hence $\Psi'(t,x')=\Psi(t,x')$, which is a step not always implied...

Comment: A simpler example might be the potential associated to an electric field.